# in reactJs onChangeHandler method is not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks, web-deployment

I am trying to make a TO DO list app using Reactjs. onChangeTitleHandler is not setting the state of title when I type the title and the same happen with the onChangeTaskHandler. the new state is not setting up.

This is the Cockpit component.

```
const cockpit = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={props.submitted}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Title" onChange={props.ChangeTitle} />
                <textarea rows={2} onChange={props.changeTask} />
                <input type='submit' value='ADD TASK'/>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is the code that I've tried.

this is my App.js file

```
import "./App.css";
import { React, Component } from "react";
import Cockpit from "./Components/Cockpit";

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    title:'',
    task: '',
    allTask : [] 
  };

  onChangeTitleHandler = (event)=>{
    this.setState={
      title: event.target.value,
    }
    console.log(this.state.title);
  }
  
  onChangeTaskHandler =(event)=>{
    this.setState={
      task: event.target.value,
    }
    console.log(this.state.title);
  }

  onSubmitHandler =(event) => {
    const tasks = this.state.allTask;
    tasks.push({
      title:this.state.title,
      task:this.state.task
    })

    this.setState={
      allTask:tasks
    }
    console.log(tasks);
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1 className="heading">Prioritise Your Tasks</h1>
        <Cockpit 
        ChangeTitle = {this.onChangeTitleHandler}
        changeTask={this.onChangeTaskHandler}
        submitted = {this.onSubmitHandler}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I want that onSubmit the new state of title and task added in to the allTask array.

Comment: I still don't understand, where I had to set ?

Comment: It is not working, it only printing the empty values on the allTask array

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on confusingly or wrongly in your example.

The main thing is that pointed out by Nils: that you are assigning a value to the `setState` function rather than using it as intended (calling it).

So instead of

```
  onChangeTaskHandler =(event)=>{
    this.setState={
      task: event.target.value,
    }
    console.log(this.state.title);
  }
```

you need to do

```
  onChangeTaskHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ task: event.target.value })
  }
```

Which leads me to one other thing that may be confusing your "output", which is that your are logging `this.state.title` immediately after calling the `this.setState` function. This won't have your expected outcome as the `setState` function is *asynchronous*, and therefore may not be as fast as you need it to for it to show the updated state in the `console.log` call.

As a latter point, from my personal point of view, your code style is somewhat confusing in the way you are naming things. Calling "`submitted`" to the onSubmit function handler sounds more of a boolean than of a function. Having properties starting with uppercase letters like `ChangeTitle` may be commonly interpreted as that being a react node or a class of some sort.

Also, for your example, a good idea would be to split the state of the task container, from that of the task itself. Having the container state being just the array, and each task item handling it's own state (title and description). This would give I think greater clarity to what you're trying to achieve.

But, conventions and clarity aside, I'd recommend that you follow the [React hands-on tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) to go through a whole bunch of concepts and good practices that may be of help and will save you a lot of time of try and error (at least this works for me)

Comment: yeah, it is working now, thanks for the help. I am new to react and just starting the learning that why naming conventions can be wrong, by the way I will definitely checking out this course.